# how to fit image to width and keep the aspect ratio in android

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, android-imageview

I have an ImageView with fixed height and width (say with width of 100dp and height of 50dp). I need to dynamically load an image to this image view.

I want this image to scale in a way that fills the ImageView's width but do keep the aspect ratio (I don't care if part of image is not visible due to height limit).

what I want is really similar to `centerCrop`, but I don't want my image to be centered vertically!

thanks in advance.

edit1:

here's my codes:

this is my layout. I want to set image for imageView with `background` id.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/background"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/footer"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/footer"
    />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/footer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp">

</RelativeLayout>
```

note that imageView is bound to size of the second RelativeLayout:

```
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/footer"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/footer"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

first in your layout add

```
android:scaleType="matrix"
```

to your imageView.

then in your java code add this:

```
ackground.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {

            Bitmap backgroundBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                    R.drawable.background_image);

            float imageRatio = (float) backgroundBitmap.getWidth() / (float) backgroundBitmap.getHeight();

            int imageViewWidth = background.getWidth();
            int imageRealHeight = (int) (imageViewWidth / imageRatio);

            Bitmap imageToShow = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(backgroundBitmap, imageViewWidth, imageRealHeight, true);
            background.setImageBitmap(imageToShow);

        }
    });
```

I will break it down for you:

at the java code you create a Bitmap object with the desired width (your imageView width) and set it to your imageView. but you need to make your imageView scaleType to matrix to prevent android from automatically scaling it!

Comment: is it possible to do this exact thing without converting the drawable to bitmap? it's really slow for my use.

Comment: Do you have any idea how long I've been searching for exactly this! +1

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you have got `Bitmap` image, namely *imageBitmap*, and `ImageView`, namely *myImageView*. Here's how you resize it so that it fills whole width of your imageview keeping the aspect ratio:

```
float imageOriginalWidthHeightRatio = (float) imageBitmap.getWidth() / (float) imageBitmap.getHeight();

int imageToShowWidth = myImageView.getWidth()
int imageToShowHeight = (int) (imageToShowWidth / imageOriginalWidthHeightRatio);

Bitmap imageToShow = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(imageBitmap, imageToShowWidth, imageToShowHeight, true);
myImageView.setImageBitmap(imageToShow);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. It worked with a little tweak of my own :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just set the height of ImageView to e.g. 50dp, and try to change the scaleType to one of those described in this link: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html. I don't remember which does what.

Comment: it doesn't work! I've been fighting with this for days now. the closest scaleType I came across was centerCrop, but I don't want the center feature!!!

Answer (score 0):

To create an image with width equals screen width, and height proportionally set according to aspect ratio, do the following. Here I mention how to load image to imageview from url.

```
Glide.with(context).load(url).asBitmap().into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, GlideAnimation<? super Bitmap> glideAnimation) {

                        // creating the image that maintain aspect ratio with width of image is set to screenwidth.
                        int width = imageView.getMeasuredWidth();
                        int diw = resource.getWidth();
                        if (diw > 0) {
                            int height = 0;
                            height = width * resource.getHeight() / diw;
                            resource = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(resource, width, height, false);
                        }
                                              imageView.setImageBitmap(resource);
                    }
                });
```

Hope this helps. :)